# Handle multiple customers with their own database in Django

Tags: database, django

I have to develop a Django webapp which can handle several customers with their own databases.

Each customer should manage their different users and groups, with associated permissions and a set of Django's apps.

I need separate databases for security and scaling reasons. Moreover, each base size may exceed 200MB. Besides these dedicated databases, I need a "common" database to store data common to every customer (and must not be replicated to every customer database).

The fact is that I don't know how to handle the multiple customers databases (and keeping Django's auth capabilities for each customer independently : user/group/perms).

I found django-constance (https://github.com/comoga/django-constance) which allow to change settings on the fly, and I have in mind to auth with a customer identifier + username ; this way I may load the right DB with the customer identifier and auth on that one with the username.

Well, this solution does not seem to me so good, and I would appreciate if anybody has a better idea or if someone has already encountered this problem and found a workaround...

I have not found similar problems on the net, and that's quite annoying because that does not seem to me as unusual...

Thanks a lot for the time spent on this.

Answer (score 0):

Keep It Simple -- leverage what Apache (or nginx or whatever) offers you.

1. Use mod_wsgi.
2. Use Apache (or nginx or whatever) to split the customer's URL's from each other

   ```
   /cust1/path/to/resource
   /cust2/path/to/resource
   ```

   If you use Apache (or nginx or whatever) to split these things up, then each top-level path element can direct the request to a specific mod_wsgi instance
3. Each mod_wsgi instance has it's own `settings.py` that has the customer's specific database credentials.
4. Each customer `settings.py` should probably start with `from master_settings import *` so that you can have a "for all customers" settings which is extended by each specific customer.

Comment: Thanks for the idea S.Lott !
Unfortunately, my company does not use Apache but nginx with Django projects, and we use the built-in webserver for development.
I would prefer use a native solution in django if I find a workaround...

Comment: @leo: "native solution in django"?  Too complex.  Use `nginx`.  That way each Django installation for each customer is nearly identical and the customers are kept completely separate from each other.  No little slip-up will pollute one customer's mod_wsgi daemon with another customer's data.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll search for some information on WSGI to check how I can integrate that with nginx and django.